# Unable to run Laravel Composer Update - RAM and Swap file limitation - VPS

Tags: php, composer-php, vps

I recently subscribed to hostinger vps with 1GB ram. But i cannot run composer update.

> [ErrorException]
>         proc_open(): fork failed - Cannot allocate memory

The problem is i cannot run composer update because of the RAM limitation. I tried setting the ram limit to 512m to 768m to -1 but it still doesnt work. I still get the RAM error Issue.

```
 php -d memory_limit=512M /usr/local/bin/composer update
 php -d memory_limit=768M /usr/local/bin/composer update
 php -d memory_limit=-1 /usr/local/bin/composer update
```

I also tried the swap file but unfortunately, hostinger doesn't allow swap files. i cannot use the swapon command.

> swapon: /swapfile: swapon failed: Operation not permitted

I am looking for help on the options so that I can run a laravel project on the vps with 1GB ram.

I tried all the suggestions on the docs but none helped.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#proc-open-fork-failed-errors

I am really in a bind here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could run `composer update` locally and upload the updated `composer.lock` file and run `composer install` on your hosting which is less memory intensive

Comment: you shouldn't be running composer update on anything other than your dev environment

Comment: if 1gb is still not enough then you can just upload your vendor directory or go for more memory (or switch hosting)

Comment: @apokryfos is correct, do what he is suggesting

Comment: thanks @apokryfos i will try that and i think i will just upgrade my subscription to 2GB.

Comment: What's the reason for using `composer update` on a vServer? Why not run that locally, as suggested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @apokryfos , running

```
composer update
```

on the development machine then committing the updated `composer.lock` file and then running

```
composer install
```

on the live server resolved the problem.

Thanks to all who answered.